# How to call a YUI panel/dialog without a button

Tags: ajax, yui

I am building an OS type GUI. I have a start menu that is like Windows. I need to be able to call a panel (newPanel.show()) without it being a button. When I use the right call out of a button it refuses to show the panel or div. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YAHOO.example.container.simpledialog1.show();
```

Hope this will help. :))